# Writing on Delta Table with Change Data Feed enabled

Tags: pyspark, delta-lake, delta

I'm trying to update with a merge statement a Delta table that has the property `delta.enableChangeDataFeed=true`, but I get the exception `AnalysisException: Cannot write to table with delta.enableChangeDataFeed set. Change data feed from Delta is not yet available`.
Doing a bit of research I found some old issues on Github that explained that writing on CDF enabled Delta tables was possible only inside Databricks platform, that runs (I believe) a different/proprietary version of Delta. Is it really possible only inside Databricks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change Data Feed is available in Delta 2.0 and above. Make sure to use the proper version that [works with your version of Apache Spark](https://docs.delta.io/latest/releases.html#compatibility-with-apache-spark).

Comment: This is the correct answer in general, my specific problem was that I had not updated maven dependencies